# How to get key information in scala code whit tool jar?

Tags: java, scala

I wanna to parse `scala` code in my java project and get some key information in this code, like class name or if exist main method. this code maybe from file or String.

for example, there is a tool named `qdox`, it can use to parse java code and get key information.

how to use qdox:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.qdox</groupId>
            <artifactId>qdox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
```

in java project, use qdox api i can parse java code:

```
String code = "package demo;" +
            "  public class Demo{" +
            "      public static void main(String[] args) {\n"+
            "        System.out.println(123);"+
            "      }" +
            "  }"
JavaProjectBuilder builder = new JavaProjectBuilder();
JavaSource src = builder.addSource(new StringReader(code));
String packageName = src.getPackageName();
```

now, i get the key information -- `packageName="demo"`.

so, i want to ask, is there a similar tool jar to parse scala code?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Java Reflection?

Comment: What do you mean _from scala code_? Do you have a jar to read from? Do you have a Scala file in your project? Do you want to read it from maven?

Comment: A sample of input and output would help understand the problem better.

Comment: thanks your suggest, I revised my question and add a case

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve that requires such functionality?

Comment: Maybe this: https://scalameta.org/